python3 dowgrade in ubuntu 22.04.1
to be able to install ros2, need python3=3.10.6-1~22.04 but system wide python is 3.10.12
sudo apt install python3=3.10.6-1~22.04

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.10.6-1~22.04) but 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 is to be installed
Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.10.6-1~22.04) but 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


NEVER try to replace system python; use other methods for your special needs. I personally recommend PyEnv ...

to be able to install 'ros2 humble or jazzy' , systemwide python should be 3.10.6.1
venv would not work in this situation

The install an older Linux that comes w/ your required python version.

tried 22.04 and getting the "unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop ubuntu 22.04"

@tink ROS distros are tied to linux distro releases. If the OP is required to use a specific ROS distro they can't downgrade to an older version of linux.

In that case I guess the packagers stuffed up and they're SOOL... @BTables

It can be installed https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.6/ from python.org
